# MVC 5 - Show item details in the same page when item is selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I use the sample code located here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC5-Demo-with-Entity-c6bc81df

Basically this is a CRUD sample for movies database where you can create read, update and delete them.

My question is: how can I show the details of a selected movie when clicking on `Details` link on the same page?

At the moment when clicking details you are redirected to the controller and action that will display the info about that movie.

Can I show the details on the same page where movies are listed?

Comment: ajax and partial view can be a valid option

Comment: Either load details on click with ajax as said by @Infer-On or if there arent many, for the selected items, you can bring down detail as part of the model. Hide it with CSS and show/hide as required with JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but they all come down to making some sort of Ajax call to load the partial view. The following is a working implementation, albeit minimal:

**The Model - Movie.cs**

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public string Genre { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I'd recommend a view model here, but that seems a bit out of the scope of the question at hand.

**The Controller - MoviesController.cs**

```
 public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private readonly List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>
    {
        new Movie { Title = "SomeTitle", Price = 23.25M, ID = 1 }, 
        new Movie { Title = "AnotherTitle", Price = 123.25M, ID = 2 }
    };

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View(this.movies);
    }

    public PartialViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        return this.PartialView("_details", this.movies.First(x => x.ID == id));
    }
}
```

**Partial View - _Details.cshtml**

```
@model YourProject.Models.Movie

<hr/>
<h3>Details</h3>

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price)

...etc

<button type="button" id="clearDetails">Details</button>
```

**Main View - Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<YourProject.Models.Movie>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var detailsPartial = $('#details');

        $('.details-link').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data) {
                    detailsPartial.html(data);
                    $('#clearDetails').click(function () {
                        detailsPartial.html(null);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Movies</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Title)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Price)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var movie in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = movie.ID }, new { @class = "details-link" })</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => movie.Title)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => movie.Price)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="details"></div>
```

Put this altogether and you're left with a view wherein one can click details, Ajax will retrieve the partial view HTML from the server and insert it into the specified div tag.